# Which Extensions are you using with 4.7 which do not yet state they have a 4.7 release

Tags: extension

Not sure if this is a valid question for SE, but I thought it as good a place as any to try and assess what Extensions people are successfully using with 4.7.x even where the extension does not state that it is compatible with 4.7

My sense - and very happy to be proven wrong - is that a good many may work, they have just not been tested by the developers, or no-one has updated the release information for them

Answer (score 1):

There are two major hurdles preventing my extensions from working:

a) settings storage has changed. Unlike many extensions, mine remove their settings when uninstalled.

b) cj being removed in 4.7 as a valid JS format. My extensions need (in theory) to work on 4.4 and I don't think that allows CRM.$

In short, I'm not convinced that they can be made to work without splitting the codebase along versions somehow.

Comment: For JS files using jQuery, I usually wrap all the code with a closure. If do this, you could refer to `cj || CRM.$` -- e.g. https://gist.github.com/totten/9591b10d4bc09c78108d

Comment: Phenomenal! I didn't know that was a thing. Do you have an example of how you wrap it in the closure? I know how this is done in jQuery I just want to see it in this context. I.e. if the CRM.$ enclosure contains cj

Comment: Examples besides the gist? I think a majority of *.js files in civicrm-core provide examples of using a closure, e.g. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/js/crm.searchForm.js . Note how (aside from the last line) one would never refer to `cj` or `CRM.$`; instead refer to `$`.

Comment: Mine use closures, just not the cj || CRM.$ bit :)

Comment: `cj` has not been removed in 4.7, FYI. But maybe someday it will be. Tim's suggestion seems like a good safeguard.

Answer (score 1):

bgm says [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=37098) that the Region Lookup extension works for 4.6, and would require a small fix to work with 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

CiviRules is reported as working as far as it's been tested.  See:  [CiviRules and CiviCRM 4.7](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/civirules-and-civicrm-4-7/9860#9860)

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would put up something I can maintain as a useful list

CiviRules (G H: [SE post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/civirules-and-civicrm-4-7/9860#9860))

[Email API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api)

Region Lookup - discussed [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=37098)

Answer (score 0):

[Email API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) is working happily on 4.7 along with [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Multisite Permissioning](https://civicrm.org/extensions/multisite-permissioning) in production for a couple of weeks now.

Ditto for [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) - but watch out for [CRM-18115](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18115), a core bug that might affect you if you use Summary Fields with smart groups.

I've also successfully testing inbound/outbound SMS with [Twilio](https://civicrm.org/extensions/twilio-sms-provider).